# regex check second letter of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a fun little task. I need to set a variable to true if:

string ends in a letter or the second digit in the string is either a "p" or "r".

So far, I have

```
var endingIsLetter = Regex.(myString.length - 1) ??? magic here.
```

Any help? My regex buddy is on a dead laptop.

EDIT -- REGEX is not required. I just thought it would be the easiest way to get this done. Any examples are welcome.

Comment: Why would you use RegEx for something as simple as that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use Regex for that?

```
var flag = char.IsLetter(s[s.Length - 1]) || 
           s[1] == 'p' || 
           s[1] == 'r';
```

Answer (score 3):

Recall that `.` represents a single character, `^` is an anchor for the beginning of string, `$` is an anchor for the end of string, and `[pr]` is any single character from the list between the square brackets.

```
^.[pr]
```

means "second letter is `p` or `r`.

```
[A-Za-z]$
```

means "the last character is a letter".

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc123", "^.[pr]|[A-Za-z]$")); // False
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc12x", "^.[pr]|[A-Za-z]$")); // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("apc123", "^.[pr]|[A-Za-z]$")); // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("arc123", "^.[pr]|[A-Za-z]$")); // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("", "^.[pr]|[A-Za-z]$"));       // False
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/hPI9AD).

Comment: You should probably put it together in one regex using `|`

Comment: `^.[pr]|[a-zA-Z]$` I guess)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use regular expressions? or is this optional? Because code without regular expressions might actually be faster. :)

To match the second character in a string: `^.[pr]`
To match the last character in a string: `[a-z]$`

Combined: `^.[pr]|[a-z]$`

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `$` matches the end of the string
- `.` matches any character (except line breaks depending on your settings)
- `[...]` provides a selection "any of these", where you can define ranges as well
- `[a-z]` represents any character from the range `a` through `z`. Note that this does **not** include things like umlauts.

Note that the regular expression above expects case-insensitive matching to work properly (otherwise you'd have to add the uppercase characters as well): `^.[PRpr]|[A-Za-z]$`

To get a quick preview of regular expressions (in case I'm unsure) I prefer the [Regex Hero Tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = Regex.Matches( @"\w(p|r)+*\w", "Eppressio9n" )
```

Argh, I just kinda did this out of the blue because I have to leave for work at the moment.

I forget what Regex.Matches returns, all you got to do is check if there is anything that returned from Regex.Matches.

Hope this helps